# Correct way to spell "young'un"?

Tags: orthography, contractions, eye-dialect

As slang, this phrase:

> Since I was a young'un...

Is there an accepted way to abbreviate the last word there?

Comment: Did you look up the expression in a dictionary before asking here?

Comment: Agree with @Mari-LouA ... this is a simple reference check.

Comment: I think this is potentially a very interesting question. I'm pretty sure that I've seen it rendered as both _young'un_ and _young'n_ in different places—and Merriam-Webster's Online doesn't provide an entry for either form.. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to determine relative popularity in this case, in part because Google Ngram Viewer doesn't handle terms with embedded apostrophes well. Good luck with your quest for an answer!

Comment: [youing 'un](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/young-%27un)

Answer (score 5):

Harold Wentworth, *American Dialect Dictionary* (1944) has an entry for

> **young one, young'un, youngin, yo'ng-un, youngern**, *n.* A child.

with citations to instances of multiple additional spellings as well between 1840 and 1941.

Since the spellings in all instances except "young one" are imitative of the way people pronounce the term in spoken English and since Merriam-Webster (at least) shows no inclination to weigh in on the relative popularity of the various spellings, I think you're probably safe with any formulation that strikes your fancy, though my guess is that *young'un* is the most common spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's a space between the two words, and that the apostrophe before the second is a 'close quote' mark, rather than a vertical tick mark.